# Android: How to retrieve the result to be returned by the current Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Android question: I am currently in Activity A and inside of A I start Activity B using `startActivityForResult`. At different points in B I can set different values as the result using `setResult`. While I am still inside of Activity B, is there any way for me to check what will be the current result that will be sent back to Activity A? (Or do I have to keep track of this information myself?) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javanator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467592/javanator) is right - the best way is to keep track of the result yourself.

However, you can make it a bit easier on yourself if you use the `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)` form of `setResult`. If you maintain `data` as a field in your `Activity` class, then you can use it to track your current return status while also returning that same tracking object to the calling `Activity`.

Answer (score 3):

keep track of this information. though there can be methods that i am not aware of. but even though i would have preferred tracking it myself. maintaining a String variable and a getter for this in my class